# Rails has_one :through association: setting the associated object will delete the joined object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have

```
class CarpoolGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :carpool_group
  has_many :car_types
end

class CarType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  has_one :carpool_group, through: :car
end
```

When I set

`car_type.carpool_group = nil`

or when I save the `carpool_group`, the joined `Car` object got **deleted** from the DB. I see the SQL `DELETE from "cars" where ...` after I set `car_type.carpool_group = nil`.

How do I keep the `has_one` through association and avoid this deletion?

Answer (score 1):

Rails always deletes intermediate records for `through` associations because Rails does not consider intermediate records as independent entities, but as connectors between entities.

In your case you have two options:

**Option 1:**

Call  `carpool_group = nil` directly on `car`:

```
cat_type.car.carpool_group = nil
```

**Option 2:**

Replace `has_one` with `delegate`:

```
class CarType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  delegate :carpool_group, to: :car, allow_nil: true
end
```

When original code `cat_type.carpool_group = nil` will not delete the car.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify CarType's association to Car.. before the has_one decleration

```
class CarType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  has_one :carpool_group, through: :car
end
```

Comment: Actually, I have that in my code. It was a typo. Thanks for pointing that out. Updated.